# Exist some way to extract the correlation-Id property from of a MQ message using AMQP?

Tags: ibm-mq, quarkus, amqp, smallrye

I have a microservice that is subscribed to a topic and receives messages using the AMQP protocol. This microservice reads the correlationid value in order to set the response with this same correlation. The problem is that whoever publishes on this topic does so using the MQ protocol and I want to know if there is any compatibility between MQ and AMPQ protocols to obtain this value.

The microservice takes the body of the message correctly because apparently there is compatibility in that part but it does not obtain the correlation when an attempt was made to take the metadata. The library I am using is Smallrye

I tried to get the value from the metadata but I got null. I understand that it is because the original message is not set with AMQP but with MQ.

Comment: Is there any compatibility between MQ and AMPQ protocol to obtain the correlation Id? It should be available as message property "correlation-id" as documented here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=mammf-mapping-mq-fields-onto-amqp-fields-outgoing-messages. If you think you meet all system requirements, then this might be a support case.

Comment: Please also consider the correl Id of the MQ message might not have been set by the message producing application. This is what you might want to check first. This wouldn't be unusual application design.